# Deep copy of UIImageView didnt copy all the delegate and gestures thats applied on the orignal one in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates, uigesturerecognizer

This is my copying code how im  coping the object

```
 - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {

    dragable *obj =[[[self class]allocWithZone:zone ] init];
    if (obj) {
        obj->startLocation=startLocation;
        obj->_firstX=_firstX;
        obj->_firstY=_firstY;
        obj->_lastRotation=_lastRotation;
        obj->_lastScale=_lastScale;
        obj.center=self.center;
        obj.frame=self.frame;
        obj.bounds=self.bounds;
        obj.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
        obj.image=self.image;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

dragable class is the custom uiimageView class with some delegates and gestures applied on it here some internal detail about the dragable class

```
@protocol draggableDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void) currentObjectClicked:(UIImageView* )object;

@end

@interface dragable : UIImageView<NSCopying,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    CGPoint startLocation;
    CGFloat _lastScale;
    CGFloat _lastRotation;
    CGFloat _firstX;
    CGFloat _firstY;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<draggableDelegate> delegate;
@property (atomic,retain ) CAShapeLayer *marque;
@property (atomic,assign ) CGPoint startLocation;
@property (atomic,assign ) CGFloat _lastScale;
@property (atomic,assign ) CGFloat _lastRotation;
@property (atomic,assign ) CGFloat _firstX;
@property (atomic,assign ) CGFloat _firstY;



@end
```

an the gestures applied are in the same class like that

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)] ;
[pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)] ;
[rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)] ;
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapProfileImageRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)] ;
[tapProfileImageRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapProfileImageRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tapProfileImageRecognizer];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

so the point is i'm coping the dragable object as in above (top most) code its working with the object now i want to copy all the GestureRecognizer and delegates applied on the dragable's object so when i use the copy i should not apply all the GestureRecognizer and delegates separately to its copy

Answer (score 1):

If your gesture recognizers are always the same for your class, set them inside your initializer, so that they are recreated in your copy when you call `init` in your `copyWithZone:` method (they have to be recreated anyway since one gesture recognizer instance cannot be associated with multiple views).

Copy your delegate in your `copyWithZone:` method the same way you copy your other instance variables (`obj->delegate = _delegate;`).

Also note that the designated initializers for `UIView` are `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:` rather than `init`, and that there is no need to set `center`, `bounds`, and `frame` at the same time because they modify each other. Just use `initWithFrame:` instead of `init` (unless you have moved the origin of your bound rectangle).

```
dragable *obj = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithFrame:self.frame];
```

Answer (score 0):

> just added the line

```
obj.delegate=self.delegate;
```

in the coping argument list you can see that below

```
 dragable *obj =[[[self class]allocWithZone:zone ] init];
if (obj) {
    obj->startLocation=startLocation;
    obj->_firstX=_firstX;
    obj->_firstY=_firstY;
    obj->_lastRotation=_lastRotation;
    obj->_lastScale=_lastScale;
    obj.center=self.center;
    obj.frame=self.frame;
    obj.bounds=self.bounds;
    obj.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
    obj.image=self.image;
    obj.transform = self.transform;
    obj.delegate=self.delegate;
}
```